# get python argparser attributes into script namespace

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I used to do this in my python scripts:

```
import sys
my_int = int(sys.argv[1])
...more commands...
```

How can I replicate THIS EXACT functionality with the argparse module?  Do I need to extract all of the variables from the parser? That would be tedious.

I don't want an answer like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--my_int", type=int, dest="my_int")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(**vars(args))
```

because I want to be able to interrupt my script in ipython and have all the variables still be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
locals().update(vars(args))
```

is the answer